# Rails / Rspec: Having an anonymous controller be of a certain class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

My controllers inherit actions from `ApplicationController`. My goal is to test the behaviour of any controller that inherits from `ApplicationController`. I created `RandomController` in my specs in order to achieve that goal.

Here is my spec so far

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.configure do |c|   
  c.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end

class RandomController < ApplicationController; end
class Random < ApplicationRecord; end

RSpec.describe RandomController, type: :controller do
  controller {}

  describe '.index' do
    context 'when no record exists' do
      before { get :index }

      specify { should respond_with(200) }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is `application_controller`

```
class ApplicationController
  def index
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

The issue is that when the `index` method runs, `self.class` returns `#<Class:0x00007f8c33b56fc8>` instead of `RandomController`. Is it possible to have my anonymous controller be an instance of a given controller (declared within the specs) ?

Comment: may you can try `self.class.name' when the binding stops

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you can specify the base class for the anonymous controller:

> To specify a different base class you can pass the class explicitly to the
>   controller method:

```
controller(BaseController)
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller

Thus you can probably call:

```
controller(RandomController)
```

in your specs

Comment: There is some improvement but it still doesn't do what I want it to do. When specifying the controller, the action is called from an instance of `#<Class:0x00007fe551e30df8>` whose superclass is `RandomController`. The issue is that the method still isn't called from `RandomController`.

Comment: Why can't you test it with `RandomController` instance as a `subject` then?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`shared_context`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/example-groups/shared-context) instead of creating a `RandomController` to test shared code:

```
shared_context 'an application controller' do
  describe '#index' do
    context 'when no record exists' do
      before { get :index }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end
end
```

You would typically put this file under `/spec/support`. Example:

```
/spec/support/shared_contexts_for_application_controllers.rb
```

Then, in each controller that inherits from `ApplicationController`:

```
describe RandomController do
  include_context 'an application controller'
end
```

Comment: I need to do some processing on `RandomController`. For example I retrieve the name of the model based on the controller's name. I'm not sure shared context is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by _retrieve the name of the model based on the controller's name_? Are you looking to do this processing in `RandomController` only for the tests? Could you please update the question with said "processing" code?